# Not getting the correct timezone in java

Tags: java, eclipse, timezone

The code that I am using to get the current timezone in java side is as follows:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));

System.out.println("the timezone is--->"+(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")).getDisplayName());
```

It is displaying as `pacific Standard Time`
but the current time zone in america/los angeles is `pacific daylight time`

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the parameterless [`getDisplayName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDisplayName%28%29) method whose documentation includes:

> This method is equivalent to:
>
> ```
>  getDisplayName(false, LONG, Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.DISPLAY))
> ```

The `false` here is the argument which specifies "don't use daylight saving time". So the parameterless method will *never* display a DST variation.

It's not clear that you really *should* usually display a name based on the *current* standard/daylight part - but if you really want to, you can use:

```
String name = zone.getDisplayName(zone.inDaylightTime(new Date()), TimeZone.LONG,
                                  Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.DISPLAY));
```

Obviously you should customize the second and third parameters according to your requirements.

Comment: Hi jon can u please help me with the correct syntax?
Thank you :)

Comment: @user2451522: Well what's wrong with the code I've already given you?